# Is it possible to move closed questions off of the "related" links?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

In the list of "related questions", is it possible to remove the links to closed questions, or at least demarcate them as closed in the list?  Example:

Related:
Question X
Question Y
Question Z

Related but CLOSED:
Question A
Question B

Questions that are closed are closed for good reason (off topic, complete duplicate), and having to come across questions that are already recognized as poor is time consuming.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but this would require a change to the Stack Exchange software, so someone from the development team will have to comment on it.

Comment: I'm moving to Meta.SO, it would be more visible there.

Comment: @mbq: It's already been asked on MSO, and [the current status is "by-design"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/related-questions-include-closed-questions). If - while discussing this *here* - you can come up with some better reasons for why the current behavior is inappropriate, please contribute them to that thread.

Comment: Since this is being handled on the main meta site already, at the link Shog9 provided, I'll close it as off-topic here (even though it's not really off-topic, at least not in a bad way).

Comment: This question should be migrated to meta stack exchange as mbq suggests.